# BeautifulSoup adding extra whitespace before and after each opening and closing tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the Sample program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import HTMLParser

soup = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

html = soup.new_tag('html')
head = soup.new_tag('head')
body = soup.new_tag('body')

html.insert(0, head)
html.insert(1, body)
soup.insert(0, html)

blockquote = soup.new_tag('blockquote')
sourceStr = "This is <i>My Website Title</i>, just for example."
blockquote.insert(0, BeautifulSoup(HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(sourceStr), 'html.parser'))
soup.body.insert(1, blockquote)

print soup.prettify()
```

It generates the following output:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <blockquote>
         This is
         <i>
         My Website Title
         </i>
         , just for example.
      </blockquote>
   </body>
</html>
```

Which actually displays in the browser like:

> This is *My Website Title* , just for example.

The extra whitespace is getting added between "My Website Title" and the following comma. How can I avoid adding extra whitespace by BeautifulSoup?

**Without using any string operations is there a way to handle this problem using BeautifulSoup methods if any?**

Comment: Actually, I am trying to handle this problem using BeautifulSoup methods if any exists. I don't want to use any string operations on sourceStr.  @RobBricheno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating a `tag` that you know you don't want to pretty-print, you can manually patch its `preserve_whitespace_tags` after creating it, as follows:

```
blockquote = soup.new_tag('blockquote')
blockquote.preserve_whitespace_tags.add('blockquote')
```

I think that's probably the closest thing to what you want here, without having to write an enormously complex parser.